# Can't connect Python kernel jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I can't connect my Python kernel to Jupyter. This is weird cause I can run R kernel which is in the same path.

```
jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  ir         /X/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  matlab     /X/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/matlab
  python3    /X/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

kernel .json

```
    {
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```